# Javascript ~ How to send a message in a specific channel discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

As you know recently discord.js has moved to v13. I try to send a message in a specific channel but it gives me an error. Here's my code:

```
let channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID)
channel.send(`${MSG}`)
```

This is my error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Please help me. I've tried finding similar topics here and the only solution I found was in typescript but I want it in javascript.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try fetching the channel, or fetch the guild first

Answer (score 1):

Using `client.guilds.cache.get("ID").channels.cache.get("ID").send()` should help!

Comment: Doesnt work. Now the error is in red letters saying 'channels is not defined'

Comment: can you tell me how are you using my answer in code? Cuz it should work just fine

Comment: The first ID needs to be the ID of the guild, and the second should be the ID of the target channel, like so: `client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID").channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID").send()`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```js
let channel = GUILD.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID);
channel.send(MSG);
```

Answer (score 1):

discord.js v13 needs you to specify which events you want your bot to receive. To achieve this you need to select, so called "Gateway Intents".

[Here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html) is a guide on Gateway Intents and how you configure them. 
[Here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents) is a list of all Intents and what events they allow your bot to receive.